# Changing the input data in logstash using a filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have my input data from a table. The table data looks like 
`<Customer_id> <Item_id> <Item name>`. For every item brought by customer, there is a separate row in the table. For example, if c1 buys i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 It will have 5 rows in the table.

Now the data that I want to insert into elasticsearch is in this some way:

```
{
  "c1": [
    {
      "item_id": "i1",
      "item_name": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "item_id": "i2",
      "item_name": "XYZ"
    },
    .....
  ],
  "c2": [
    {
      "item_id": 4,
      "item_name": "PQR"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I modify the input as above in logstash ?

Also my schema looks like this :

Item :
      item_id , item_name

Buy:
      cust_id, item_id

Also Can you please suggest the SQL query to be made in order to get the above output?

Comment: Are we talking about an SQL table? If yes, can you show their respective schema?

Comment: Yes. So the schema is like :  
Customer_ID Varchar2(10) 
Item_Id Varchar2 (10)
Item_Name Varchar2(100)

Comment: I think we need another discriminant than just the customer, since I guess the same customer could be buy items on different days (i.e. in different orders). Do you also have an order_id column or something?

Comment: Yes, I do have that.. It is just a sample description and not the actual one. I just want to understand so as to how I can transform this sort of input to the type of document I want to insert into elastic search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is by creating an SQL query that groups those rows on `Customer_ID` together and uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to gather all items of the group.

Then, you can use the [logstash jdbc input](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) with the SQL query you came up with above and you should be good.

**UPDATE**

I've reworked your SQL query a little bit like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('{"',cust_id,'": [',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"item_id":',buy.item_id,','),CONCAT('"item_name": "',item.item_name,'"}')), ']}') 
FROM item, buy
WHERE buy.item_id = item.item_id 
GROUP BY cust_id
```

which produces rows like this, which are pretty close to what you need:

```
{"1": [{"item_id":1,"item_name": "abc"},{"item_id":2,"item_name": "xyz"}]}
{"2": [{"item_id":4,"item_name": "pqr"}]}
```

Comment: Were you able to try this out?

Comment: Yes, But this doesn't seem to be working. Because it instead of giving  
{
      "item_id": "i1",
      "item_name": "ABC"
    },

it gives
GROUP_CONCAT(item_name,item_id)": "ABC1".

Can you help me in this?

Comment: I can if you show your query, please update your question with it :)

Comment: Updated with the schema details.

Comment: Can you share your current SQL query please?

Comment: SELECT cust_id,GROUP_CONCAT(buy.item_id,item.Item_name) from item,buy where buy.item_id = item.item_id group by cust_id;

Comment: In logstash, when I write this sql query as it is in statement, I get  
Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 10, column 49 (byte 349) after input {  

and when I use \ with ' characters, I get a JAVA exception: Syntax error in SQL query. 

How to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the opening and closing braces. Please try again. But of course you need to properly escape all the quotes and double quotes.

Comment: When I am escaping all the quotes and double quotes, it gives me JAVA Exception : SQL Syntax error.

Comment: Well, you need to update your question with whatever logstash configuration you have, so we can reproduce this.

Comment: It worked. But now I am getting a new error  "failed to execute bulk item (index) index " while putting data to elasticsearch.

Comment: Good progress so far! But that's probably worth another question, so we don't cram too much into this one.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you so much for this. Will create a new question for that then!

Comment: Great, glad to help!