# Logstash MySQL combine multiple rows

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have been playing around with logstash and have been able to insert some of my MySQL tables to Elastic search.

Now, I need to combine multiple rows from the a MySQL Query statememt into one document. For example, lets say I have a mySQL query and I have the following result,

```
1   Group1  Company1    User1
1   Group1  Company1    User2
1   Group2  Company2    User3
1   Group2  Company2    User4
```

I would like to create 2 Group documents in Elastic Search for Group1 and Group2. Inside Group1, I will need to add User1 and User2. Inside Group2, I will need to add User3 and User4.

Is this possible using LogStash and combining with some Filters? If so can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: These answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36982705/4604579 + http://stackoverflow.com/a/34691171/4604579

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [logstash-filter-aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#_example_4_no_end_event_and_tasks_come_one_after_the_other). The filter takes a `task_id`, in your case the group field, and aggregates the rows that have the same task_id value. So, events with group1 will be aggregated, then when the filter detects a new group value, the aggregated user data for group1 will be pushed as a single Logstash event to output to your elasticsearch document. Then, it starts the process over with group2.

Make sure the logstash filter workers are set to 1 (`-w 1` flag or in the config file) and the rows are ordered in a way that all of group1 events come in, then all of group2 etc. Otherwise the events may be processed out of sequence and can have unexpected results/data loss.

```
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{group}"
    code => "
      map['users'] ||= []
      map['users'].push(event.get('user'))
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout_tags => ['aggregated']
  }

  if "aggregated" not in [tags] {
    drop {}
  }
}
```

The result will look something like this:

```
"_source": {
  "group": "group1",
  "users": ["user1", "user2"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I will give this a go and let you know.